# Cant build react native project for android in windows 10

Tags: javascript, android, facebook, react-native, cross-platform

when im tring to build my project it geving me this error

```
    Checking the license for package Android SDK Build-Tools 23.0.1 in C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\licenses
Warning: License for package Android SDK Build-Tools 23.0.1 not accepted.
Checking the license for package Android SDK Platform 23 in C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\licenses
Warning: License for package Android SDK Platform 23 not accepted.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> You have not accepted the license agreements of the following SDK components:
[Android SDK Platform 23, Android SDK Build-Tools 23.0.1].
Before building your project, you need to accept the license agreements and complete the installation of the missing components using the Android Studio SDK Manager.
Alternatively, to learn how to transfer the license agreements from one workstation to another, go to http://d.android.com/r/studio-ui/export-licenses.html
```

but i tried add licences forder to sdk path it didnt worked.i update the all of my skd platform and sdk tools.but still im getting this error.how can i fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Use android.bat from the Android tools direcory and install all dependencies using that instead. You will then be asked to accept licenses when downloading/installing.

Comment: How to install dependencies from Android.bat file?

Comment: Simply run the android.bat file - you will be presented with a UI where you can choose the required dependencies. You would then install Android SDK Platform 23.

Comment: I ran the bat file but it didn't open any interface.its disappeared